# Is it efficient to read the contents of a file into an unordered_map if it has over 1000 entries

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, unordered-map

I'm making a hash table that's supposed to give pretty fast lookup time for some values I type before hand. I didn't know how to go about it but my friend said I should make a text file and just have an unordered map that reads from the text file and puts the values in the code before I run it. Is this efficient? Is there a better way to do this?

Also side note, the values are supposed to be structures. Is it going to be possible to read them into the code with an unordered map?

Comment: On a modern computer 1000 things is basically zero. Have you tried it? Was it acceptably performant? It sounds like you're talking about < 1MB of data which is trivial.

Comment: Just make sure the map is created only once at Startup/first use and not every time the code runs.

Comment: @Axel how do I do that? Because my code contains map initializers. Won't that delete whatever was originally stored?

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, your idea is good enough unless these structures are really large, megabytes.

If you have reasons to worry about the performance of that, e.g. if you want to support millions of records or very large values, more complicated approaches can be more efficient.

When I only need 64-bit support, I sometimes make a single binary file, optimized for memory mapping the complete one. Specifically, a fixed-size header, then sorted arrays of (key,offset) tuples serving as a primary index (can use binary search there, the OS only fetches required pages from mapped files and it caches them in RAM in quite aggressive manner), then values at the offsets specified in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::map when

1. You need ordered data.
2. You would have to print/access the data (in
3. sorted order). You need predecessor/successor of elements.

Use std::unordered_map when

1. You need to keep count of some data (Example – strings) and no ordering is
   required.
2. You need single element access i.e. no traversal.

> Also side note, the values are supposed to be structures. Is it going to be possible to read them into the code with an unordered map?

Definately you can but i hope you knew that you cannot read file with map `fstream` is there for that purpose.